# Subtracting values of one column from another using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I am working with a very large set of data (Leukemia Cancer) for my thesis and i have to process all of them. The condition is something like i have an excel file where there are 20 patients name in the columns, and they have 2000 rows of data for each of them, now i have to find the maximum and minimum value in each column meaning for each patient, Then subtract the minimum value from the maximum and then divide it by .5 and export the value for each patient, I am using Pandas.

i was able to find the max and min value using

```
data.max(), data.min()
```

for exporting the values i used -

```
data.min().to_csv('min.csv') and data.max().to_csv('max.csv')
```

which is two separate file.

Now what i need to do is make sure there is only one file with two column showing maximum and minimum value side by side and also the value after subtraction in the third column and the final value after dividing in the last.

Sample data:

```
Patient No  Patient1    Patient2    Patient3    Patient4
gene data1  5614.705569 6446.177102 5756.830799 5498.327075
gene data2  592.8588927 401.8615001 459.7095671 619.2129817
gene data3  246.4022014 238.535468  261.7679828 207.4747361
gene data4  1273.25497  1318.80054  1338.271733 1221.564705
gene data5  51.0906811  37.07419033 26.28092875 37.12742504
gene data6  756.0119839 867.248239  956.754366  864.2708979
gene data7  168.4100068 153.3151275 136.5111169 205.8874617
gene data8  183.0011027 277.4930516 191.5097325 140.7178783
gene data9  1334.627713 1480.547871 688.3688018 3269.536931
```

Final output:

[image: Final Output]

I hope This clear what i am trying to Do.

Finding the Maximum and Minimum value for Each Patient Column From 2000 Rows of Data, Then Using this formula 0.9/Max-Min and export all the data for each patient in a csv in column.

I am sorry i just started using Python. So any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could provide a [MCVE]. An explanation such as the one you have provided gets confusing if we can't see what you're trying to do. For your problem, maybe you could provide a toy dataframe with 3 patients and 10 rows, for example, as well as your desired output

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, i am new here and exploring the proper ways to question, Will update it right now.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'patient1': [1,2,3,4,5], 'patient2': [3,5,7,8,11], 'patient3': [5,9,13,17,21]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
min_df = df.apply(min,axis=0)
max_df = df.apply(max,axis=0)
sub_df = max_df - min_df
div_df = sub_df/0.5
out_df = pd.concat([min_df, max_df,sub_df,div_df], axis=1)
out_df.index.name = 'Patient'
out_df.columns = ['min','max','div','sub']
out_df.to_csv("out_all.csv")
out_df.T.to_csv("out_all_patients_as_columns.csv")
```

Hope you get the idea, adapt appropriately.

Comment: Thank you so much , Can you check the next reply i gave that should clear out what i am trying to do, I am not able to edit my original question due to low points as a new member.

Comment: Try out the answers, if it works for you, please accept the best answer.

Comment: It's working for the values you provided, but i have the excel file ready which i imported, now i need the run the code on that ,  can you see this answer i gave should clear things out : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51331321/7529936